# Side effects of assigning a pointer value to a variable in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, variable-assignment

I'm running into some strange problems when assigning the reference of a pointer to a variable: the local code works correctly, but it causes memory access errors elsewhere:

```
//This works fine
Gridcell* g = model.gc;
cout << g->LC_updated << " " << g << endl;

//When I include this, the program crashes elsewhere
//But output from this line is OK
Gridcell gc = *g;
cout << "Var:" << gc.LC_updated << &gc << endl;
```

(Gridcell is a class, which doesn't have a no-args constructor)
I'm not a C++ expert, and this is a fairly large external library, but I can't understand why an assignment to a locally scoped variable should cause problems elsewhere. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `Gridcell` has a proper copy constructor. This is only required if `Gridcell` manually manages resources, which almost never should be the case. If it the the case for you, you will need [The Big Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

If you need more specific help, post the class definition of `Gridcell`, along with constructors and destructor, if you have them.

If your intention is not to copy, you can use a reference:

```
Gridcell & gc = *g;
cout << "Var:" << gc.LC_updated << &gc << endl;
```

The usage is the same, but it will not create copy.

Comment: Where is the copy happening? Does
    Gridcell gc = *g;
create a copy of the object pointed to by g?

Comment: @mo-seph: Yes, that statement creates a copy.

Answer (score 3):

You don't give enough information to solve the problem. There is nothing inherently wrong with the code you've posted.

My guess is that `Gridcell` lacks a proper copy constructor and so when `gc` goes out of scope it deletes things that `*g` is still referring to.

This line of code:

```
Gridcell gc = *g;
```

is where the copy constructor is being invoked.  It's essentially equivalent to saying this:

```
Gridcell gc(*g);
```

which invokes the `Gridcell::Gridcell(const Gridcell &)` constructor, otherwise known as the copy constructor. The copy constructor is special in that if you don't have one, the compiler will automatically generate one for you. The automatically generated one typically just invokes the copy constructor of each individual member variable, including the pointers. For basic types, like `int` or `Foo *`, the copy constructor simply makes an exact copy.

For example, if you have code like this:

```
class Foo {
 public:

   Foo() : msg_(new char[30]) { strcpy(msg_, "I'm Foo!"); }
   ~Foo() { delete [] msg_; }

 private:
   char *msg_;
};

void aFunction(Foo *aFoo)
{
   Foo myfoo = *aFoo;
}

void anotherFunction()
{
   Foo localfoo;
   aFunction(&localfoo);
}
```

It will crash. `localfoo` will allocate character array. The line `Foo myfoo = *aFoo` will call the copy constructor which will make a straight copy of the pointer. Then the destructor for `myfoo` will be called and the memory will be freed. Then the destructor for `localfoo` will be called and the memory will be freed again, resulting in a crash on many systems.

Comment: By default, the copy constructor does a shallow copy (i.e. pointer values are copied). So, the destructor, if it deletes members, deletes the memory used by the original object as well, so the pointer in the original object is pointing at freed memory.

Comment: Thanks both Omnifarious and Skizz, that really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Is model.gc a local variable?

If so, when it goes out of scope it ceases to exist.  And any pointers to it are no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

@Space_C0wb0y is right.

Imagine that you have attributes in your `Gridcell` class that are pointers (arrays or objects that are explicitly allocated through `new`).

When you assgin an object of type `Gridcell` from another one, the *default* copy constructor makes a *shallow* copy. It copies the value of those pointers, but does not create new objects/arrays for the new attributes of yout new object.

If you split

```
cout << "Var:" << gc.LC_updated << &gc << endl;
```

in two lines:

```
cout << "&gc" <<&gc << endl;
cout << "Var:" << gc.LC_updated << endl;
```

You will probably see that the fault goes to the line where your reference `LC_updated` (I don't know what is it).

Check your constructors to see how it is being initialized.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help - the fault doesn't happen here. It's because the destructor gets called on gc when it goes out of scope, and that destroys the object pointed to by g, which is used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
GridCell gc = *g;
```

Does a copy of the instance pointed by `g`. If the `GridCell` does not define a copy-constructor (a constructor of signature `GridCell(const GridCell& other)`), then a default one is provided by the compiler that does a copy of each member. For member that are of a pointer type, this is just a copy of the pointer, and thus both `gc` and the instance pointed by `g` will point to the same memory.

When the `gc` variable goes out of scope, its destructor is called. If the `GridCell` class does manage some memory, does not provide a copy-constructor (or it is incorrect), and release the memory in its destructor, then the `GridCell` instance pointed by `g` will point to released memory after this point.

Generally, when a class manage some memory, it must override the destructor, the copy-constructor and the assignment operator. This is the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Please note that the assignment will also perform slicing if `g` point to a subclass of `GridCell` and that can also bring other problems. If you want to use the `gc` variable as an alias not to have to use `*g` everywhere, you should consider using a reference (or a const-reference) instead of making a copy (especially if the object does manager lots of memory, copy can be expensive).